Connect two devices with different subnets
I have a problem where I need to connect one system to another that exist on different networks. How do I do this. I have tried using this NAT configuration:
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.10 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.80
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.10

But I get no response when I ping 192.168.1.10.
SYSTEM_A IP: 192.168.2.80

SYSTEM_B IP: 192.168.1.123

I want to connect SYSTEM_A and SYSTEM_B but I can't get it to work, I have a Teltonika RUT300 router.

What is your subnet mask? Usually having your subnetmask set correctly is all you need to do. With ranges 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x, a subnetmask of 255.255.254.0 should work.

@LPChip I think you're off by one – a /23 only covers either subnets 0+1 or 2+3, but not 1+2 (you need a /22 for that). Also, that only works if both are on the same ethernet, and OP hasn't clarified that yet – if there's a router separating the two networks, setting such a subnet mask will only have negative results...

@grawity_u1686 ah, you're right.
